# A component for dynamic multiple group entries

Tags: jsf, dynamic, input, components, development-environment

I have come across a situation where in a form a customer needs to enter address. A customer can have more than one address and further the address field contains more than one text fields,combo boxes etc. A customer can dynamically add more address and remove any address entry. Eg: there is one add button on form, which when clicked will display all address fields as a group. if the user wants to add more address then he/she can again click the add button, so that a new entry for the address fields will be displayed. Also each corresponding new entry will have a delete button so that if the user wants to delete the entry then he/she can. Finally all the address entries should get mapped to a backing bean.

eg: in backing bean one has " private List address" and Address class further has street,pincode,state,city etc.

Is there any jsf ui component that can help out in the above scenario. In short, a user can enter more than one address dynamically and then a list of address gets mapped to the corresponding entry in backing bean..

Please guys, contribute for this, i am sure that this kind of component will make development way simpler.

The component should have the facility of describing our own sub group items. here in the above case it was address, but in different cases one might require it to be something else like mobile number, websites,email address etc. The component should be fully customizable ie. from group entries to mapping it.

Please developers, develop this kind of component and tell me from where and how can i start to be a part of it. If we all come together we can develop this wonderful component which will make development lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a a few ideas for you based on your narrative:

1. Make a form of `<h:inputText>` components bound to properties (`Strings`?) on your Backing Bean.
2. Make up a Class which describes a User's Address - `UserAddress()`?
3. Create a `<h:commandButton>` whose `actionListener` calls a method on the same backing bean, which creates a `UserAddress()` object from the values of the Strings on the backing bean, and then add it to a `List` of type `List<UserAddress>` on your Backing Bean.

Most JSF components are geared up to accept Lists of objects, so you'll be in a good position to then use such a component to loop over your `List<UserAddress>` to put all the user addresses on the screen.

There are plenty of [component libraries](https://blogs.oracle.com/rlubke/entry/jsf_component_libraries) out there to choose from.  One which immediately comes to mind from the currently popular PrimeFaces library is the editable [DataTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableEditing.jsf).

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you , it worked. also i found out the collector component of the prime faces . It does exactly what i wanted